# How to get a message count set to group in Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-email, google-api

My company uses Google Apps for domains. Our email is a customized Gmail address. We have several groups set up—i.e. support@mycompany.com, which is a group containing the email addresses of several users. We need a way to see how many messages were sent to that group address during a certain time period.

Is there a way to do this, either pre-existing or via one of the Google APIs?